# At two hours past midnight, should I refer to the day that officially ended at midnight as "today" or "yesterday"?

Tags: word-choice, time

If I am still awake two hours past midnight, thinking about what I have done since the last dawn, should I call the day that officially ended at midnight "yesterday" or "today"?

To my native Spanish speaker’s ears, both ways sound idiomatic, especially if the events recalled happened close before midnight. Is it the same in English?

Comment: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: You yourself referred to it as *the day that officially ended at midnight*. If you respect that "official" position, you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

{I think you'll find decent references hard to come up with here.}

Personally, I wouldn't use either expression at 2 o'clock in the morning. Favourite would be a plain 'midnight', if context disambiguated, as it normally would:

- *Hello, John. You've made good time getting home. I wasn't waiting up for you; I started to read a new book around midnight as I didn't feel at all tired.*

If absolutely necessary to add clarity, I'd use 'midnight just gone'.

- *The news came through at midnight just gone.*

12am/pm have largely been consigned to history as the endpoints belong (or don't belong) equally to both sides of the exact time, and 'midday'/'noon' // 'midnight' are usually used instead. But this does not help with identifying *which* midnight if adding 'today' (though I'd say most would think of the midnight to come). The differing opinions about the meaning of 'midnight today' on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/3klpy7/does_midnight_refer_to_today_or_tomorrow/) illustrate the ambiguity problem

Similarly, 'this night' without clarifying context. 'Next Tuesday' may also be (and is) taken two ways.

Comment: The OP's question is implicitly answered by his use of *officially* within the question. In some strict sense, the time before midnight is yesterday. However, most people who are awake at 2AM are involved in some activity that straddles the midnight, and so may naturally think of that moment as a part of the day in which the activity started.  Often, however, it may not be clear how 'official' the context is, and that's why the advice given here, to avoid either term, is generally sound.

Comment: Perhaps my question will be clearer with an example. Suppose a man is still awake at 2 a.m. on Tuesday, finishing the correction of a text that he wrote between 10 p.m. and 11 p.m. on Monday. Would the man consider the text he is still correcting as the text that “I wrote today” or “I wrote yesterday”?

Comment: That's a different question. ' ...the text that I wrote today' is unacceptable here, but ' ...the text that I wrote yesterday' is improbable, unidiomatic here. You'd say 'the text that I wrote earlier ... late last night, actually'.

Comment: Also, if I read an ambiguous reference, I am confused. But if I draft the words, I am not going to introduce confusion. I have choices other than today or yesterday, especially when I notice they are confusing: I just wrote, wrote a few hours ago, I am finishing, wrote Monday evening ...